# Error toggle se muestra y esconde repetidamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Mi problema reside en que tengo un panel que deseo mostrar y ocultar con el click de un botón, en una página funciona correctamente pero si entro en otra cualquiera se ejecuta el toggle otra vez sin dar click en un plazo de 1 segundo.

Esto es lo que hace que se muestre si está oculto, pero si estoy en otra página que no sea la principal se muestra y se esconde enseguida, sin saber porque dado que el archivo JS es el mismo.

```js
$('#user-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $($(this).data('target')).toggle("fast");
});
```

```css
#menu-toggle {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    header #user-toggle { }
    
    #main-menu, #user-menu {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(41,92,144, 0.85);
        padding-top: 10px;
        z-index: 9999;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <button id="user-toggle" class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" data-target="#user-menu">
                          name
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Falta información, evidentemente hay alguna diferencia entre las páginas. O bien en alguna se ejecuta el `click()` del botón o el `toggle()` del elemento. Los fragmentos que muestras no están completos.

Comment: @Fly la página es la misma dado que uso el navbar, la parte de arriba funciona en algunas páginas si y en otras no. Debuggeando un poco he descubierto que por algun motivo el evento onclick es llamado 2 veces, he estado revisando en todo mi código y solo está declarado una vez

Comment: Prueba a cambiarle el nombre del ID y poner otro a ver si sigue haciendolo

Comment: @Hsbrg el id del boton, del nav?

Comment: Del botón y de la declaración del `.click()`, por si se está llamando desde el código.

Comment: @Fly cambiando el ID del botón se sigue llamando dos veces

Comment: ¿recargas la pagina cuando vas a *"otra pagina que no sea la principal"*? verifica la información: ¿seguro que el click se ejecuta dos veces o solo es que se oculta? porque si recargas la pagina el estilo por defecto es `display:none`

Comment: @Fly se ejecuta dos veces, he cambiado mi código del click por un alert y el alert sale una vez al mostrarse y al esconderse automaticamente 1 segundo despues se vuelve a mostrar. No refresco ninguna página ni nada, el apartado del navegador sigue arriba, lo que cambia es la parte de bajo, donde no hay ninguna llamada al boton ni evento

Comment: ¿que mas se ejecuta en el click? ¿quien recarga la parte de abajo?

Comment: @Fly el click es el que ves, simplemente muestra un div en el nav para que el usuario vea su perfil ahí

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92561/discussion-between-fly-and-alberto-martinez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución ha sido evitar que llame dos veces al evento, para esto jQuery incluye la función `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` que evita eso mismo, de esta forma se ha solucionado el problema de la llamada doble. Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Documentación: [Documentación sobre el stopImmediatePropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)